# Has Google Collections 1.0 been mavenized?

Tags: java, maven-2, guava

According to the [entry at MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections), at the time of this writing, the latest version in maven central is 1.0-rc5.  I am aware there are no changes between 1.0 which was recently announced and RC5, but I guess the nit picker in me wants to find a 1.0 version.  Here's the POM entry for RC5.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 1.0 of google-collections (which is final since the 30 dec 2009) is available in central since... the 30 dec 2009: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/. Don't trust mvnrepository, go see yourself (or use a better [solution](http://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~google-collections) to search central and other Public Repositories).

Comment: Because I made the foolish assumption that mvnrepo was synched fairly often and I was aware that the 1.0 announcment was awhile back.  Indeed, central was updated what 10 days ago?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1. http://mvnbrowser.com is also a good one site for searching aritifacts, surely more up-to-date than than mvnbrowser.com

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep your own local repository and add the 1.0 version to it? Add it to your list of repositories in your OS-dependent USER-HOME/.m2/settings.xml

Info on this is available at: [Introduction to Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Then you won't be reliant on it being on a given central repo or mirror, and you'll be able to use google-collections-1.0 in your POM. It also eases the burden on the public repos when artifacts are kept on a local server and only on occasion does something new get brought in from a central repo..

Now, if it's a shared project you'd probably need your repo to be public, but if not then it should be pretty simple to set something up.